# JavaFX Print WebView as PDF only prints one Page

Tags: java, javafx

I try to Print the content of a WebView via the Microsoft Print to PDF printer.

This is my code:

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
Scene scene = new Scene(root,1920,4000);
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().
      getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.load(url.toString());
scene.setRoot(browser);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);

...

if(printerToUse != null) {
   PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
   job.setPrinter(printerToUse);
   PageLayout pageLayout = printerToUse.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, 
   PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
   job.printPage(pageLayout, browser);
   job.endJob();
}
```

I get prompted to choose a save Location and a PDF is printed but it contains only one cropped page of the WebPage. Even if I choose a pageLayout with A0 (the page would definetely fit that) I just get a cropped one Page PDF. 
How can I print the whole area that is displayed in the WebView?

Comment: How does your `application.css` look like?

Comment: The application.css file is empty

Answer (score 1):

Instead using `job.printPage()`, try to use the `print()` method of the WebEngine object. 
For example:

```
if (job != null) {
    webEngine.print(job);
    job.endJob();
}
```

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that printing an ImageView node gave a very poor result on my printer, so I opted for another approach which gives me excellent print results.
If you have your PDF as a file or a byte[], you could use a `java.awt.print.PrinterJob` in combination with Apache's PDFBox. Here is a snippet with my code:

```
public Optional<PrintService> print(byte[] pdf) throws MyPrintException {
    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdf)) {
      PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
      job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
      if (job.printDialog()) {
        job.print();
        return Optional.of(job.getPrintService());
      }
      return Optional.empty();
    } catch (PrinterException | IOException e) {
      log.error("Print error", e);
      throw new MyPrintException(e);
    }
}
```

However be aware that this only works when `headless=false`. In Spring Boot the default is `headless=true`. Fortunately there are many post describing various way the configure `headless=false`.